# Similar to std::transform function for cv::Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm wondering is there any function in OpenCV, which operates with two `cv::Mat` objects alike `std::tranform` in STL?

For example,

```
cv::transform(src1, src2, dst, bin_function);
```

where

- `src1` and `src2` : input matrices (cv::Mat) of the same size.
- `dst` : output matrix of the same as inputs.
- `bin_function` : binary function or function object that accepts two elements as argument (one of each of the two matrices), and returns some result value.

I tried to search in documentation but not found such thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such function in OpenCV yet. However, you can use the STL algorithm `std::transform` on the `cv::Mat` iterators like this:

```
std::transform( src1.begin<float>(), src1.end<float>(), 
                src2.begin<float>(), dest.begin<float>(), bin_function );
```

Be sure to use the right template type argument. So if you have a 3-channel matrices with 8 bit for each channel for example, then use `Vec3b` instead of `float`.

Beware of the usual STL pitfalls though. `src1`, `src2` and `dest` should have the same number of elements before your call to `std::transform`. If you need this genericity, you may consider to write a wrapper function `cv::transform` yourself, which checks that, reserves memory for `dest`. Finding the right type for the template argument dynamically will probably be difficult, since the `bin_function` needs to accept all possible arguments. However, even that may be possible in certain specific cases, if you use C++14 lambdas with `auto` parameters.

Comment: Works fine. FYI, in my version of OpenCV (2.4.9) there is no need to specify iterators type (functions begin and end are not template).

Comment: Well, that's even better then. Awesome!

Comment: @brotherofken What? How they can then be typed appropriately, given that a `cv::Mat`'s type is determined at runtime? Maybe you're using a `cv::Mat_<T>`?

Comment: @ChristianRau You are write. I'm using Mat1f. I did not paid attention to it.